# Google Translate API: XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Origin http://test.dyndns.org is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I just gained API access to Google Translate API v2 and I'm using my API key in the AJAX request, but I keep getting this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=[myKey]&source=zh-CN&target=en&q=%E6%82%A8%E5%A5%BD%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%0A.
>   Origin http://[mySub].dyndns.org is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I've read all the similar posts, but I still can't figure out what the problem is. Note that the following conditions are true:

1. I'm hosting this on my own Apache server at home via dyndns.org, so I'm not using local file reference in the browser. I actually have an http://[mySub].dyndns.org that matches the error message and I'm not using any funky ports either. I'm using port 80. The server and the client, however, are the same machine.
2. I'm using Google Chrome 13.0.782.220 m on Windows. I don't see this error in IE or Firefox, but the callback function also doesn't work on those browsers.
3. The link in the error message actually works fine.

Here's my jQuery...

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: {
        key: '[myKey]',
        source: 'zh-CN',
        target: 'en',
        q: '您好世界' // Hello world
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    failure: function() {
        console.log('failure');
    }
});
```

I hope it's something obvious!

Comment: Try: `datatype: 'jsonp',` instead of just `json` - see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: same here.. I want it in jQuery. No response from the ajax call in Firebug.. Accessing the URI with REST works fine. Bountied!!

Comment: jQuery v1.5.1 - nothing Ricky :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working example thanks to [CD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320736/google-translate-api-xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-origin-http-test-dyndns-org-i/7402990#7402990) = awarded

```
var apiKey = "YOUR-API-KEY-HERE";
var langSource = "en";
var langTarget = "it";
var apiurl = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=" + apiKey + "&source=" + langSource + "&target=" + langTarget + "&q=";
var text = 'This is a test string';

$.ajax({
    url: apiurl + encodeURIComponent(text),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        // console.log(data);
        console.log(data.data.translations[0].translatedText);
    }
});
```

Comment: working examples are the best! thanks. and it works perfectly well on my end too :)

Answer (score 5):

You should be useing `jsonp` instead of `json` for the dataType.

Have a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/H9mfd/

Answer (score 1):

Very helpful. +1.

Here's the provided example that loops through a JSON object to replace to values:

```
var dictionary = {"term" : "term"};
    var apiKey = YOUR API KEY;
    var langSource = "en";
    var langTarget = "it";
    var apiurl = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=" + apiKey + "&source=" + langSource + "&target=" + langTarget + "&q=";
    var newDictionary = {};

 $.each(dictionary, function(key, value) {
    $.ajax({
       url: apiurl + encodeURIComponent(value),
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       success: function(data) {
          var localO = new Object();
          localO[key] =  data.data.translations[0].translatedText;
          $.extend(newDictionary, localO); 
       }
    });
 });

//newDictionary == {"term": "italian translation"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try starting Google Chrome with the following flag:

> --disable-web-security

The error can be due to Google Chrome "same origin policy", a feature to avoid cross domain ajax calls

Comment: huh, really ? so you'll tell everyone "disable your security" ?

Comment: I said "try", is a common issue when you are developing in local environment with Google Chrome and are using ajax, and of course is not a valid measure in a production environment, just trying to help the OP to find the origin of his problem...